# Losing @IBOutlets after Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, iboutlet

I'm working with the Xcode view editor and Swift.

I have my main view which contains a tab bar controller with 2 tabs.
On the second tab, I have a `@IBoutlet var myLabel: UITextLabel!`. Inside `viewWillAppear` I put some text in this label.

On the first tab, I have a button which launch a third view through a Push segue, and on this new tab, I have a Back button which gets me back to the main view containing a tab bar controller (through a push segue too).

When I launch my app, go in my second tab, the text of the `UITextLabel` is changed.
I still can go to my first tab and navigate between them it works.
But the problem is when I click on my first tab's button, then on Cancel, then goes back to my second tab, my UITextLabel doesn't change. And I can't perform any action on it anymore. It's not nil though but it's like it's still connected to the first UITextLabel before the segue and not this one.

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things are wrong.

With tabbed apps, Apple says that the tab bar controller should be the root level navigation method for the app. It should always be present, and the user should always be able to tap another tap to switch to another part of the app.

So the first tab should connect to a navigation controller. When the user pushes the button, you should push a new view controller onto that navigation controller. The tab bar will still be visible and enabled, and the user will still be able to switch to view controller one.

Next thing:

You say "I have a Back button which gets me back to the main view containing a tab bar controller (through a push segue too)."

That's very wrong. Back buttons should pop a view off of the current navigation stack. They should not be pushing anything. Any time you use a push segue, you are creating and pushing a brand new instance of a view controller, and leaving the other view controllers in the navigation stack.